# Part Number of IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation v 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am not able to find the MobileFirst Platform Foundation Server V 7.1 in IBM passport advantage portal. I see the below packages but not sure which one is MobileFirst server binary.

- IBM MobileFirst Platform Cloudant Data Layer Local Edition 1.0 for Linux x86-64 (Red Hat, CentOS) English (CN3XLEN)
- IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation for iOS V7.1 zip of Installation Manager Repository for IBM MobileFirst Server Multiplatform English (CN6DCEN)
- IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Application Pattern V7.1 zip of Eclipse Update Site for MobileFirst Test Workbench Multiplatform English (CN6DFEN)
- IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation V7.1 English Multiplatform zip of IBM MobileFirst Platform Command Line Interface (CN6DHEN)

Please post if any one know the exact part number. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks PVR, looks like there is a naming confusion... this will be fixed.

Use the following: *IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation for iOS V7.1 zip of Installation Manager Repository for IBM MobileFirst Server Multiplatform English (CN6DCEN)*

Comment: Isn't that the iOS-only version? The last one in the list looks what the questioner is asking for.

Comment: The last one is the CLI. He is looking for the server installing repository.